# Basic binary_search in C++ using STL

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I am just playing with some STL Algorithms. While using binary_search I am stuck. I have sorted the vector dictionary & then I am running binary_search by writing my own comparator function. However each time the output printed is "not found". However the strings that I search for are there in vector. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the snippet:

```
bool ownComparator(const string &a, const string &b){
   return lexicographical_compare(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end());

}
...
...
cout<<"Now using Binary Search to search in sorted array"<<endl;
string searchStr="will";
bool b = binary_search(dictionary.begin(),dictionary.end(),searchStr, ownComparator);
if(b) cout<<"Found";
else cout<<"Not Found";
```

Comment: Have you sorted the vector using your own comparator function?

Comment: Works fine on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/0MZGx). Did you make sure to sort using the `ownComparator` function?

Comment: No I have used: sort(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), less <string> ());

Comment: Now I sorted using the same comparator function what I am using for binary_search even then the o/p remains same.

Comment: Do I need to trim spaces before adding strings to vector from a file? Is it because of that? Just thought.

Comment: If you are looking for `"will"`, and the string in the vector is `"  will"`, then those won't match.

Comment: Are you sure that your string is actually contained in the vector? As I mentioned the code works fine (with `ownComparator` for sorting) when tested in ideone (see [http://ideone.com/0MZGx](http://ideone.com/0MZGx))

Comment: I dont see any inherent whitespaces, I even tried matching with "will\n" thinking that a newline maybe a problem still it did not.

Comment: Got the solution: When I searched with string searchStr="will\r"; it says found that means while reading from a file, line by line into a vector a \r is appended to the string. Hmm silly mistake. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: You should test by picking a string that is actually in the vector (say `dictionary[0]`) and searching for that. If you don't find it, *then* you've got a problem.

Comment: @Dominix - A `'\r'` will be there only if the file you read from isn't a proper text file for the OS you are using. The line endings are different on Windows and Linux, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution: When I searched with string searchStr="will\r"; it says found that means while reading from a file, line by line into a vector a \r is appended to the string. Hmm silly mistake.

Comment: I'm guessing this is on a Windows machine, where newlines are `"\r\n"` and you only remove the `'\n'`?

Answer (score 0):

cout << "Now using Binary Search to search in **sorted array**"

**sorted array** are keyword. Your string is not sorted array. If you transaform string to sorted array you get alphabetical order string, such "abbbcccddddd...".

Comment: The "array" is an `std::vector` of `std::string`.